# Content Type Hub Design Considerations

Tags: content-type-hub

I created 2 Web Applications in my SharePoint environment.  What are best practices for Content Type Hub implementation?  In terms of creating it on its own Web Application or create it on an existing Web Application?  Also, is it better to create it at a root site collection level (maybe using a Team Site template - does it really matter) or a subsite inside a an existing site collection?

Curious what the communities thoughts are around this topic.

Thanks for tips provided...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a standard Site Collection in an existing Web App (don't waste resources on its own Web App). Also carefully consider the template to use - you might need different features to deploy your content types. Also do not use the Blank template. I normally use a std Team Site and then activate the necessary features.

Answer (score 1):

From a technical point of view it doesn't matter how you create it.

But usually I wouldn't use an entire Web Application for it. And I'd also not "waste" the root on it.

The only thing to really make sure is that you only use that site collection as Content Type Hub and nothing else. Again not due to technical reasons, just to make sure you only give people access to it if they need if for publishing content types.

Comment: It does matter a bit, because of the service app associations (CT Hub is hooked to the Managed Metadata Service App, and publication is per web app). Since publication is "pushed", not pulled (not subscribed to), one would need different CT Web Apps if you have specific need to isolate content type publication between different sites, and therefore require multiple CT Hubs (not a common case, but still possible...).